# Angular show and hide with ngClass for multiple divs

Tags: angular, typescript

I have multiple divs with the same class which I want to hide and show on click, also give class. when I click on EDIT, it affects all divs but I want to affect it on certain div which you click on it.

here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-2anjui?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

**.ts**

```
  isShown: boolean = true ;
  editMode: boolean = false ;

  onEdit() {
    this.editMode = true;
    this.isShown = false;
  }
  done() {
    this.editMode = false;
    this.isShown = true;
  }
```

**.html**

```
 <div class="filled" [ngClass]="isShown ? 'success' : 'danger'">
    <div class="row align-items-center mt-4" *ngIf="isShown">
    </div>
        ....
          <form action="">
          <div class="row edit-row position-relative" *ngIf="editMode">
        ......
          </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a map and assign an index for the divs:

```html
<div class="filled" [ngClass]="!editModeMap[1] ? 'success' : 'danger'">
  <div class="row align-items-center mt-4" *ngIf="!editModeMap[1]">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="ml-m@s g-b--w0 g g--alignCenter g--nowrap cur-p edit ml-auto d-flex" (click)="onEdit(1)">
        <div class="mr-xs fz-12" style="color: #737373;">EDIT</div>
        <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```js
  editModeMap = {};

  onEdit(index: number) {
    this.editModeMap[index] = true;
  }

  done(index: number) {
    this.editModeMap[index] = false;
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jnz9w3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: your editModeMap can be also a simple array: `editModeMap:boolean[]=[]`

Comment: @Eliseo for sure. I just didn't want to limit the keys to a number index; maybe OP wants to assign them with div names, classes etc.